# Spark Mllib - Predict same value for all records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have been trying to test prediction of a boolean on a set of data for a while now and i never achieved anything remotely satisfactory.
My test data look like this :

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
|ismob|cprom|ccoup|tmodals|      idxtp|   ptaddr|addrtopay|  paytthx|  paytacc|  acctthx|churncpt|churned|
+-----+-----+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|       71.0|     71.0|    161.0|   1518.0|   1496.0|     22.0|       2|   true
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      137.0|     55.0|     90.0|    151.0|      0.0|      0.0|       1|   true
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      178.0|     40.0|     41.0|    226.0|     60.0|    166.0|       0|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      236.0|     69.0|     91.0|    154.0|    115.0|     39.0|       0|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      260.0|     24.0|     47.0|    133.0|    101.0|     32.0|       0|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      281.0|     39.0|     44.0|    620.0|    465.0|    155.0|       0|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      293.0|     46.0|     27.0|     89.0|     58.0|     31.0|       1|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|      415.0|    237.0|     61.0|    277.0|    252.0|     25.0|       0|  false
|false| 0030| 6728|      1|     1149.0|   1358.0|   1378.0|    811.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0|  false
```

The last column is the one i wish to predict.

I use a StringIndexer for the boolean, cprom and ccoup columns.

I tried GBTClassifier, RandomForestClassifier, LinearRegression and other i don't remember but the result were never right.

I do the split 0.7,0.3 of my data to test the algorithm like you see in examples all the time. Usually test data have around 8000 records and 2000 of them have churn boolean to true.
Training data have around 20k records and 4000 of them have churn boolean to true.

The results are :

1. I don't have the column churncpt to the features.

   Predictions for ALL records is false. Depending on the classifier used i may have between 1 or 10 predictions to true. This is obviously wrong.
2. The column churncpt is part of the feature.

   Note that when the boolean churn is true, the churncpt column is not 0 but it is not always the case the other way around.

   The predictions here is not really a prediction at all and the churn boolean is true if churncpt > 0 which is equally not right.

I have a feeling that my training data (beside one column) are completely ignored or useless and that one column screw things over and it would be faster to do a map on my data to set the boolean using an if statement.

I also tried several parameters on each classifier to no avail. I tried ChiSqSelector on my features to prune them down but it hasn't help either.

- How do i need to structure my data for the learning to work?
- Do i have enough data in the first place?

I would gladly take any insight on predicting boolean values.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Credit scoring has been dealing with "predicting boolean values" for decades. Logistic regression is a solid starting point. Try to model a probability (i.e. values between 0 and 1) then choose the appropriate probability to place the "cutoff", which probably will not be 50% in the real world (that depends on how you ponderate false positives, false negatives etc -- the ponderation is not the same for diagnosing cancers and for calculating credit risk!!!)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried with LinearRegression and i calculated a weight column since my learning data were unbalanced.
In the end i receive a large variaty of predicted values from 0.01 to 0.1, some values are negatives like -0.017.
I have no idea how to interpret those prediction values.

Comment: I am wondered now that it is the binary classification, why not make the churned column to be 0 and 1, and use can use the Logistic Regression like models to train the data. If you use the lr model, maybe you should not let the regParam be to large, you can use such as .01 for example, so that you will not make all the training data to be all the same. After all that, you can get your prediction column to be boolean values.